# Modifying global list in python using append

Tags: python

In python to modify a global variable inside a function, we need to declare it as a global "variable" inside the function.
Example1:

```
variable = [10]
def function():
    global variable
    variable = [20]
    return
print variable # will print [10]
function()
print variable # will print [20]
```

Without global it will treat the variable as a local variable and will not modify global variable. Exmaple2:

```
variable = [10]
def function():
    variable = [20]
    return

print variable # will print [10]
function()
print variable # will print [10]
```

However I came across a situation where I need to modify a global list.
But what struck my mind is that I am able to modify global list using "append" function of list object. I have not declared variable as global inside the function. Example3:

```
variable = [10]
def function():
    variable.append(20)
    return

print variable # will print [10]
function()
print variable  # will print [10, 20]
```

My doubt is how does "append" function of list object, modifies the global variable, without having access to global variable ? If someone has explanation of this behaviour please let me know.

Comment: variable = "this is a string"
    def function():
        global variable
        variable = "this is a new string"
        return

    print variable
    function()
    print variable

In the above code, I am able to modify the global string.

Comment: If you read through the linked duplicate, you'll find that it is extremely thorough.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Okay thank you, now I am able to understand the concepts better.